# Writer.WriteLine does not change conf file contents

Tags: c#, file, streamwriter

I'm trying to edit a conf file by using line.Replace and write.WriteLine.

Debugging through the code, the line successfully changes.

Original string:

[image: Original String]

Changed string:

[image: Changed string]

Somehow after the writer.WriteLine, the text still does not change. Below is my full code:

```cs
public void ChangeFileContent()
{
   string textLoc = installPath + "\\DB\\influxdb-1.7.7-1\\influxdb.conf";
   string[] arr = File.ReadAllLines(textLoc);
   for (int i = 0; i < arr.Length; i++)
   {
      var writer = new StreamWriter(Path.GetFileName(textLoc));
      string line = arr[i];
      string output = line;
      if (line.Contains("influxdb-1.7.7-1") == true)
      {
         output = line.Replace("D:", "C:");
      }
      writer.WriteLine(output);
      writer.Close();
   }
}
```

Comment: You are writing to `Path.GetFileName(textLoc)`, which is just a file name, relative to your current directory. Is your current directory ``installPath + "\\DB\\influxdb-1.7.7-1\\``?

Comment: @GSerg textLoc is just the file which I want to change.

Comment: What @GSerg means is that `new StreamWriter(Path.GetFileName(textLoc))` starts writing to the current directory (because you only pass a filename, not a path). The output file will not be where you expect it. Look in your `bin\Debug` directory. Remove the `Path.GetFileName` to pass the full path that's in `textLoc `.

Answer (score -2):

You could build all content and write it with [File.WriteAllText](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.file.writealltext?view=netframework-4.8) or  [File.WriteAllLines](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.file.writealllines?view=netframework-4.8).

Something like the following.

```
string textLoc = installPath + "\\DB\\influxdb-1.7.7-1\\influxdb.conf";
var lines = File.ReadAllLines(textLoc);
var newLines = lines.Select(line => 
       line.Contains("influxdb-1.7.7-1")
      ?   output = line.Replace("D:", "C:")
      :    line);
File.WriteAllLines(textLoc,newLines);
```